# Constraining the length of a div to its contents

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a data grid for an `Aircraft` resource. The page has a header, a link for creating a new record, and the table. I have the following HTML:

```
<div id=body>
    <h2 class="left">Aircraft</h2>
    <%= link_to 'New...', new_aircraft_path, :class => 'button right' %>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <table>
        (omitted for brevity)
    </table>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.button {
  (omitted for brevity)
}
```

The table approximately extends to use about 25% on my screen. The `New...` button however, which is floating right, extends to far right side of the screen (100%). I need to extend only as far as the table, which is about 25%. How can I constraint the width of the div to only extend as far as the table?

[image: This picture illustrates the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the width of the table to a set number, and then wrap the button in a div with the same width. http://jsfiddle.net/j5GRH/

If the width of the table is flexible, you can add the button inside the table: http://jsfiddle.net/j5GRH/3/

Comment: The width of the table is indeed flexible, so I ended up adding the button inside the table, which does the job perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Float the div to the left. It's width will now shrink to fit the contents (i.e. the width of the table). Apply whatever extra clears you need to keep the rest of the page layout working.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! I have tried floating the button to the left, but this way it won't be aligned with the far right side of the table (as in the picture). The size of the table may vary. Is there any way to account for this?